# How can I retrieve the array inside the firestore document?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The array `doses` is the one that I wanted to retrieve, however I keep getting an error that says that map is not a function. This is what it looks like in firebase:

[image]

codes to retrieve firestore data:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(scanResult)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const arr = [];
        arr.push({
          ...snapshot.data(),
        });

        setUsers(arr);
      });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
```

mapping the users array:

```
 {users && users.map((user) => (
      <li>{user.email}</li> // I could already retrieve the data that are not inside the doses array

     {/* get the doses array does not work */}
                  {users &&
                    users.doses.map((index) => {
                      <li>{index.selectedVaccine}</li>;
                    })}
    ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `doses` field is not an array, but a map/object. An array has numeric, sequential keys, while a map/object has string keys.

If you want to loop over the keys of the field, you can do:

```
Object.keys(users.doses).map((key) => {
  <li>{user.doses[key]}</li>;
})}
```

If you instead just want to display the `selectedVaccine` value of the `doses` field, you'd do:

```
<li>{user.doses.selectedVaccine}</li>;
```